# Playing music across multiple activities using separate class

Tags: java, android

I have read from various sources that playing background music across activities requires a service. The other day I found this class, given in answer to an older question:

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;

public class AudioPlay {

    public static MediaPlayer mediaPlayer;
    public static boolean isplayingAudio=false;

    public static void playAudio(Context c,int id){
         mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(c,id);

         if(!mediaPlayer.isPlaying())           
         {
             isplayingAudio=true;
             mediaPlayer.start();             
         }          
     }

    public static void stopAudio(){     
         isplayingAudio=false;       
         mediaPlayer.stop();
    }   
}
```

Does this approach expose the app to errors or memory leaks? I tested it on a few devices without encountering a problem, and it seems much simpler than using a service.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it will, since it use a Context making the Context unable to be colected by GC as long with your class that have static fields.

If the app goes to background and the system destroy your context you will have unexpected behaviour.

The Service instance is a Context also, why don't you move this code to the Service while removing the statics?

Comment: Would it work if I used the Application Context? I would use this class to play music throughout the app, so it should only be destroyed when the app is closed.

Comment: The Application Context can also be recreated trough the lifecycle, you better using Services anyway

Comment: I will look into using a service for this, thanks. Just out of curiosity, when using the above code, would setting the static MediaPlayer to null be sufficient to release the Context?

Comment: maybe, cause it will still hold it inside and as it will create a new thread it probably will retain the context